# DHCP Discover Broadcast and its IP (255.255.255)

Tags: ip, ipv4, dhcp, broadcast

Cheers, I am trying to learn more about DHCP, and when studying about the session that DHCP goes through every one mentions that it broadcasts a discover message at IP: (255.255.255.255) (as seen [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4554/dhcp-overview-3/index.html) for example), but I can't find more info about how this IP is picked or what it signals. From my professor, I know that the last IP of a subset is the broadcast IP (e.g. 192.168.1.255, for a subset with mask 255.255.255.0), so I would suppose that's what should be used, but apparently I am thinking about something incorrectly. Can anyone provide me with some more info on the subject? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

255.255.255.255 is the broadcast address for all subnets.

Comment: Better: "for *any* subnet".